# iPhone4sだけ別のレイアウトにしたい

Tags: ios, swift

作成中のアプリでiPhone4sで起動した時だけ、あるページを全く別の画面にしたいのですが、
どのような方法でやるのが適当でしょうか。xibファイルを２種類作成し、画面サイズで端末を判定する方法を考えていますが、そちらでよいでしょうか。

Comment: Objective-C、Swiftどちらか限定で質問なさったほうが、回答がつきやすいと思います。いかがでしょうか？

Comment: Swiftでお願いします。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: @OSA タグをHarawoさんが追加してくださっていますが、追加情報は基本的に質問文に追記してください。

Answer (score 1):

デバイスによって、Storyboardを切り替える方法を考えてみます。「いや、どうしてもXibファイルの切り替えをしたい」とおっしゃるのでしたら、下のコードの中の`UIStoryboard`クラスを、`UINib`クラスに置き換えて読んでください。

このブログの記事を参考にしました。

[iOSデバイスに応じて，使用するストーリーボードを変更する](http://qiita.com/tovi_01/items/33f4d0e9d5d1d9c99263)

まず、Storyboardを複数作成します。サンプルでは、ふたつ作成し、名称をそれぞれ`Main`と`iPhoneMain`としています。Storyboardを新規に作成すると、まったくオブジェクトのない状態から始まるので、ある程度作り込んだものを複製したほうがいいかもしれません。
`AppDelegate.swift`ファイルを開き、`application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: )`メソッドを加筆します。

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // デバイスの取得
        let device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
        // デバイスのモデル名によって、Storyboardの名称を分岐
        var sbName = "Main"
        if device.model.hasPrefix("iPhone") {
            // 4s以前かどうかは、スクリーンサイズで判別する
            let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
            if screenSize.height <= 480.0 { // 高さ480ピクセル以下なら、4s
                sbName = "iPhoneMain"
            }
        }
        // 名称からStoryboardを呼んで、ViewControllerをインスタンス化
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: sbName, bundle: nil)
        if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() {
            // メインウインドウのrootViewControllerに指定
            self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        }

        return true
    }

以下略
```

`UIDevice`クラスのプロパティ`model`では、iPhoneの機種まで区別できないので、スクリーンサイズの判別と合わせ技で、iPhone 4s（以前）かどうかを調べています。
まあ、スクリーンサイズだけで判別してもいい気はしますけど。